# How to cut everything until a specific word / after a find in a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, cut

I am trying to get the output of files from today  which contain `"ERROR"`.

I use this to find the files I want:

```
find /home/user/logfilesError/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "gandalf_*"\
   -daystart -mtime -1 -exec grep -rl "ERROR" "{}" +
```

Current output (if ERROR found):

```
/home/user/logfilesError/gandalf_123.log
```

But the output I want is only the logfile name:

```
gandalf_123.log
```

Info: The path changes often so I can't just cut the letters before.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think the grep -rl especially the -l stops after at the first match

Comment: I edited my answer. How to output the answers separated by a comma is a different question. I think the answer has already been given somewhere. One way to do it is to pipe your output to `awk 'BEGIN {ORS=", "} ; {print} ; NR=$NR { ORS="\n" }'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `basename` tool can strip the path before the filename.

```
find /home/user/logfilesError/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "gandalf_*"\
-daystart -mtime -1 -exec grep -rl "ERROR" "{}" + | xargs -n 1 basename
```

will give you the desired output.

`-n 1` tells `xargs` to use exactly one argument for basename. So if it receives more, it will spawn one `basename` process per argument. This is needed as `basename` takes only one filename as argument.

This command will NOT work if your filenames contain spaces. In this case, as suggested by @HaukeLaging, use :

```
find /home/user/logfilesError/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "gandalf_*"\
-daystart -mtime -1 -exec grep -rl "ERROR" "{}" + | xargs -n 1 -d \\n basename
```

This will not work if your filenames contain newlines, though.

Comment: `xargs -d \\n basename`

Comment: @HaukeLaging Coool, how comes `-d` is not documented in the man page?

Comment: It is (and "always" has been) in mine... (`--delimiter=delim, -d delim`)

Comment: @HaukeLaging Well... just figured out, I was looking at my localized (french) man page, which is apparently not up-to-date.

Comment: Can someone help me with the edit? I dont know why there should only be one output.

Comment: Ups my bad... that's the way `xargs` functions. I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

If `./gandalf_123.log` is OK for you then you can use

```
find /home/user/logfilesError/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "gandalf_*"\
  -daystart -mtime -1 -execdir grep -rl "ERROR" "{}" +
```

Otherwise I would pipe the `grep` output through e.g. `sed` in order to delete the unwanted part:

```
> echo /home/user/logfilesError/gandalf_123.log |
  sed 's+.*/++'
gandalf_123.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`:

```
... | sed -e 's=.*/=='
```

Which tells it to replace anything up to a `/` with nothing.

You can also use `cut`, but it can't count from the right, so you have to combine it with `rev`:

```
... | rev | cut -d/ -f1 | rev
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be done with

```
 echo ${str##*/}
```

which will trim the string from left to right until last '/'

```
> str=/home/user/logfilesError/gandalf_123.log
> echo ${str##*/}
gandalf_123.log
```